# what is the function of the view.js file?

Tags: block-editor

i have made some blocks before with @wordpress/create-block now i wanted to work on a new block, and it seem there is a new file: view.js.

i have searched the web and ducomentation in the handbook, and maybe i am missing something, but couldn't find anything on it.is it there for custom javascript code ? is it only applicable for the front end?

so what is the view.js file for?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is not really relevant. You should check block.json to see where the file is actually being used. I would guess that it's being used for the `viewScript` property, in which case you can check its purpose by looking for [the documentation for that property](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#view-script), rather than anything about "view.js" alone.

As noted in the documentation, the `viewScript` file is a script that will be loaded on the front end when the block is used. This is where any interactivity your block might have would be implemented if it's not relevant in the editor.